# Create file in android app which is checked by broadcast receiver to perform an action

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-file

So currently I have a switch in an android application which when turned on creates a file (deletes the file when turned off). When I turn on the phone, the broadcast received checks to see whether the file exists or not. If it does, then it runs some setup stuff. The problem is that I create the application in the data directory (not the application's data directory). Therefore there are issues with permissions and I have to use su chmod to change the permissions access. I want to avoid this issue so I was looking at ContentProviders.

Should I go for a content provider or is there a simpler way given I don't need to read the file, just check whether it exists or not.

Could I create the file in the applications data space and access it from the broadcast receiver?

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences?

Comment: " You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed). " 

Would it persist if the phone is turned off?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in a private file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a BroadcastReceiver that has data in it.

**Send:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
intent.putExtra("on", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Receive:**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if(intent.getAction().equals("my.action.string")){
     boolean state = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("on");
  }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my.action.string" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but the issue which I think might come up is the fact that once I have the switch to the ON position and I turn off the phone, when I turn it back on, the broadcast receiver application which detects the file and executes some code will not execute anything as it does not receive the intent.

Comment: Indeed the best way to exchange that between activities seems to be http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: I was able to use broadcast receivers to communicate to the other app which then created and deleted the file. Thanks!